# What's an example of incorrect use of the ARM C Compiler Option "Enum container always int"?

Tags: c, arm, compiler-options

In http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0065d/Cihejcda.html there is an option and a note:

> **Enum container always int**
>
> Select this option to force all enumerations to be stored in integers. By default, the compiler uses the smallest data type that can hold all values in an enum.
>
> **Note**
> This option is not recommended for general use and is not required for ANSI-compatible source. If used incorrectly, this option can cause errors in the resulting image.

What is an example in C of such an incorrect use?

---

Background:

I'm developing an embedded application in C an removing this compiler flag fixed an error (or only the symptoms of another error). The error was an

```
sprintf(big_enought_char_array, "%4.1f", float_var)
```

function call wasn't correctly formatting floats.

This was almost fixed by using the right alignment for the memory used as stack. "Almost" fixed because the content of the array was ok, but the decimal point had the wrong char. Removing the compiler option mentioned above fixed the problem. So the question is what is this compiler option doing *exactly* and what is an incorrect use of it?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Floats are not connected to enums. So there seems to be another effect involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are referring to this option:

> **Enum container always int**
>
> Select this option to force all enumerations to be stored in integers. By default, the compiler uses the smallest data type that can hold all values in an enum.

In C the type used for an enumerated type is implementation-defined (but the `enum` constant are always `int`): it's an integer type that can represent all the `enum` constants.

If you set the type for enumerated type to `int` there are two issues that I can think of:

1) if you make your program rely on the fact that `enum` are `int` (for example assuming `sizeof` is the same as `sizeof (int)`), it is not portable on other systems

2) if you define a constant with a value larger than `INT_MAX` (or that an `int` cannot represent), say for example `UINT_MAX`, your type will not be able to represent it where C `enum` are guaranteed to represent it.

Regarding your specific issue with the `sprintf` call, it seems totally unrelated  with this option. You are probably invoking some undefined behavior before your call.

Answer (score 1):

> what is this compiler option doing exactly

Well, normally your average `enum` doesn't have e.g. 2³² entries -- in most cases, it doesn't even have 256. In that case, the C compiler normally is free to use a shorter representation of the value, e.g. a single byte.

Using that flag will make all `enum`s occupy the same, `int` sized (read: word-length) memory. That's only in a couple of pretty special cases, and obviously, it breaks `sprintf`; I don't think that's a usual thing to happen, so: what `libc` implementation are you using? Make sure it doesn't explicitly forbid usage of that flag, and file a bug report if necessary. Make a minimal test case to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Why does it *obviously break sprintf*?

Comment: @ringø: Marcus means "evidently", "as can be observed", rather than "it stands to reason".

Comment: or not use `sprintf` all-together :)

Comment: im using the embeeded versions of sprintf() shipped with the armcc compiler from keil. i tried an minimal test case, but im unable to reproduce it so far without my embedded realtime os running. so assume that something destroys my lookup table used in the sprintf function - if there is used one in the implementation.

Comment: @TomerW He doesn't either, that's why he's wondering why the behavior changes when the compiler flag is set (I'm guessing)

Comment: @Russ Schultz: exactly

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess with regards to `sprintf()`:

Your stack was actually declared as a `char[]` array, and it was amomg some `enum` variables or was in a `__packed` structure. Changing the `enum` from a `char` to a `int` (or the other way around) changed the alignment of the stack variables bringing the float into alignment.   (the 3rd variable of `sprintf()` being a `float` will almost certainly end up being passed on the stack)

The ARM requires the stack to be 8 byte aligned.  Best to declare it as `uint64_t` (and definitely not in a `__packed` structure) so its alignment is always right.